# fatal error ssh2_connect() while executing php scipt

Tags: php

I am really new  PHP so please bear with me. I have the following PHP code that need to be run as an executable file. However when I tried to execute I got the following error. Any help is really appreciated.
    Please note: I have compiled the below php in to a .exe file and ran it from cmdline as I am not sure how to execute a php script.

> fatal error : call to undefined funcion : ssh2_connect() in file_copy.php on line 1.

```
/*** LIVE ***/
    $server = "xxxxxxxxx";                                                                  //server IP
    $user = "xxxxx";                                                                        //login username
    $pwd = "xxxxx";                                                                         //login password

    $source_dir = "G:/A/B/C/D/";    //directory the exe file is placed at 
    //directory the exe file is placed at
    $destination_dir = $source_dir;                                                             //change to external File Server (if needed)

    $log_file = $destination_dir."file_copy.log";                                           //path to log file (if does not exist it will create a file)
    $file_name = $argv[1];                                                                      //param 
    $file_path = $source_dir.$file_name;                                                        //full path


    echo " Execution starts ... ";
    echo " file to execute ($file_name)";
    echo " $file_path";

    //error check
    if ( !is_file( $file_path ) )
    { 
        write_log($log_file, "File does not exist  ($file_name)", $source_dir);
        //exit;
    }

    //read local file
    $fp_local = fopen($file_path, "r");
    $buffer = fread($fp_local, filesize($file_path));
    fclose($fp_local);

    //create connection
    $connection = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
    if(!$connection)
    { 
        write_log($log_file, "Could not connect to server: $server ($file_name)", $source_dir);
        exit;
    }

    //authenticate  
    if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pwd )) 
    { 
        write_log($log_file, "Authentication failed: incorrect password for user $user while transfering ($file_name)", $source_dir);
        exit;
    }

    //create session    
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

    //write a file on remote server
    $fp_remote = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$file_name", "w");
    $result = fwrite($fp_remote, $buffer, strlen($buffer));
    fclose($fp_remote);



    //move file to log folder
    if ( !$result ) 
    {
        write_log($log_file, "Failed to transfer ($file_name)", $source_dir);
        exit;
    }

    $copy_to = $destination_dir."copied_to_".$server;
    if ( !is_dir($copy_to) ) { mkdir ( $copy_to , 0755 );  }
    $status = rename ( $file_path , $copy_to ."/".$file_name) ; 

    //printing some information
    echo " ... MOVING: ". $file_path;
    echo " ... TO: ". $copy_to ."/".$file_name;

    if($status)
    {
        write_log($log_file, "SUCCESSFUL Transfer ($file_name)", $source_dir);
    }
    else
    {
        write_log($log_file, "Transfered ($file_name), but failed to move file to copy_to_dir. Please notify Maconomy Support", $source_dir);
    }

    exit;


//write to log file
function write_log($log_file, $status_text, $source_dir)
{   
    $text = date("m.d.y G:i:s") . " :: " . $status_text . " \r\n";

    send_a_mail('TMS :: '.$status_text, $text, $source_dir);

    if (!$handle = fopen($log_file, 'a')) {echo "Cannot open ($log_file) (TEXT = $text)"; return false;}

    if (fwrite($handle, $text) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write ($log_file) (TEXT = $text)";
        return false;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

//send email
function send_a_mail($subject,$message,$source_dir)
{   
    $message = "<b>$message</b><br><br>";

    $email_to = read_email_address($source_dir);

    if (!preg_match("/SUCCESS/i", $subject))
        $email_to[] = "XXXX.XXXX@XXXX.com";

    $to = implode(', ', $email_to);
    $to_headers = implode('>, <', $email_to);

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version:' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: <$to_headers>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: TMS <XXXX.Support@YYYYYY.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: XXXX.Support@YYYYY.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer' . "\r\n";

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

//read email address
function read_email_address($source_dir)
{   
    $filename = $source_dir.'email_address.txt';
    $content = '';

    if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) {echo "Cannot open ($log_file) (TEXT = $text)"; return false;}
    $content = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);

    $email_to = explode(',', $content);

    return $email_to;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the PECL ssh2 extension installed?

Comment: Thanks Shamil, I don't know if it is insalled or not. How can Iinstall it/ leasesugges

Comment: user3319970 check the results of `phpinfo()` for it.

Comment: I am not sure how to or where to run phpinfo().Let me explain my situation, I do not have php installed on my machine. But I have to run the above script inorder copy the files accross to an SFTP server. I have converted the above script in to .exe file and running it from cmd. Please let me know how can I get rid of this error.